# udev rule to start a command on AC/Battery plug/unplug event

Tags: linux, unix, arch-linux, udev

To save battery, i'd like to turn off effects (compositor) whenever laptop runs on battery.
I thought of achieving this with udev rules.

- Created a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-myrule.rules` :

```
ACTION=="change", SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply", RUN+="/usr/bin/startcompton.sh"
```

This rule is supposed to trigger every time you connect / disconnect AC from laptop.

I then update rules with: `sudo udevadm control -R`

Sadly, this does not trigger anything when connecting / disconnecting my power supply.

My system is Arch linux.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR:**

1. Make a udev rule execute a script to kill your application (compton) on AC disconnect.
2. Starting it again is not straightforward - Make a systemd service to start your app, then use a udev rule to start that service.
3. To test your udev rules, use `udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger`

---

**Answer:**

So I found a working solution. The question was made of 2 questions so let's break it down:

1. Write udev rule to run on AC/Battery plug/unplug.
2. How to start a gui application like compton from a udev rule.

### Write udev rule to run on AC/Battery plug/unplug:

create file `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-onbattery.rules`:

```
# Rule for when switching to battery
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply",ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE}=="0",RUN+="/bin/killcompton.sh"
```

and create file `/etc/udev/rules.d/61-onpower.rules`:

```
# Rule for when switching to powersupply
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply",ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE}=="1",RUN+="/bin/startcompton.sh"
```

Notice how `POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE` is from environment, surrounded by `ENV{...}`

Also, if you'd like to know the attributes for your own rules, monitor what the udev sees with:
`udevadm monitor --environment`

If your script is simply a background task and not calling any GUI-related processes, then your'e done!
Otherwise, keep reading:

### How to start a gui application like compton from a udev rule:

From [udev man](https://linux.die.net/man/7/udev) about using RUN:

> "This can only be used for very short running tasks..."

Which means we should use something persistent like a *systemd* service.
Create a service file: `/etc/systemd/system/compton.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start compton

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=%h/.Xauthority"
User=USERNAME
ExecStart=/bin/compton --blur-method kawase --write-pid-path %t/compton.pid
PIDFile=%t/compton.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Replace `USERNAME` with your user name.

`%h` and `%t` are specifiers replaced by `$HOME` and `/run` or `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`. See `systemd.unit(5)` for more details.

The line `Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/USERNAME/.Xauthority"` Is a must if you want a GUI application. Please see [This Answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85244/setting-display-in-systemd-service-file).

And finally, in your udev rule, instead of starting your GUI application (in our case compton), start the service:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply",ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE}=="1",RUN+="/bin/systemctl start compton"
```

Comment: To restart udev: # udevadm control --reload-rules && udevadm trigger

Comment: Great reply, thank you! Using the monitoring command (`udevadm monitor --environment`) I finally figured out why it does not work: my device does not have **POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE** but uses **POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS**, which is set to "Charging" or "Discharging" - and this finally made my rules work :)

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer got me started but I figured I'd share the final result for me - my use case was to do something (actually power cycle a smart plug/relay because of a weird PSU issue) when a laptop lost AC power.

I got tripped up because udev rules shouldn't be multi-line and if they are they should be escaped.

Here's what I ended up with:

```
# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/90-onbattery.rules                                                                                                                                                                                   
SUBSYSTEM=="power_supply",\
  ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_NAME}=="ADP1",\
  ENV{POWER_SUPPLY_ONLINE}=="0",\
  RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl start power-cycle-outlet.service"
```

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/power-cycle-outlet.service                                                                                                                                                                         
[Unit]
Description=Power Cycle Outlet via Home Assistant

[Service]
User=root
Type=simple
GuessMainPID=false
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/trigger-outlet-powercycle.sh
```

`trigger-outlet-powercycle.sh` makes a network call so it can't be invoked directly from udev due to the sandbox, and I couldn't get `at` working but systemd worked fine.

Interesting resources, which could be used to improve the above:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Udev#Spawning_long-running_processes
- https://blog.fraggod.net/2012/06/16/proper-ish-way-to-start-long-running-systemd-service-on-udev-event-device-hotplug.html